# special charactor handling in xstring

Tags: xstring

I want to handle a string of characters to get my desired string by the package xstring, here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{xstring}

    \begin{document}

    \StrBefore{aaa \bfseries bbb;some other text}{;}[\temp]
\temp

    \end{document}
```

The output string I want is "aaa \bfseries bbb",but the code fails to compile.
I think the reason is the existence of "\bfseries", the character "\" causes the failure.
Anyone can help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Removing `\bfseries` doesn't fix the problem, so I guess that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Removing `\bfseries` and `[temp]` or removing `\bfseries` and changing `[temp]` to `[\temp]` works though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a "\" in [temp]. I just corrected it. And, I don't want to remove "\bfseries", the oupput string I want should contain it,that is to say  "aaa \bfseries bbb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand what you want (printing `\bfseries` as a result and not interpreting it). This can be done by changing it to a string with `\string` or `\detokenize`. Note that in the default font the backslash is printed as high ticks if you use this option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrBefore{aaa \detokenize{\bfseries} bbb;some other text}{;}[\temp]
\temp\\
\StrBefore{\detokenize{aaa \bfseries bbb;some other text}}{;}[\temp] % works, too
\texttt{\temp}% with \texttt the backslash is printed

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the OP wants `\bfseries` to have its usual effect

Comment: @egreg "Many thanks, Fischer. But the text "\bfseries" disappear in output of \temp. How to keep it? " is what he wrote as comments under Ulrike Fischer's answer. Based on this, I thought he doesn't and because of this, I wrote this answer.

Comment: @egreg but reading onward I guess, I misinterpreted it.

Comment: @Skillmon by the marco \detokenize, I get the wanted string format. Then in later call (yes, in later call after the string has been handled), how to make \bfseries excute ?

Comment: @lyl how much string handling do you need? The `\bfseries` is also persistent in Ulrike's answer. The `\detokenize` macro does what it's called, it detokenizes its argument. I don't know any way how to revert that later on. If it's just the splitting of the string you need, go with Ulrike's answer. You should maybe give us the complete use case, so we can provide working answers for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to prevent the expansion of \bfseries:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{xstring}

 \begin{document}
 \noexpandarg  
 \StrBefore{aaa  \bfseries bbb;some other text}{;}[\temp]
 \temp

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Might it be a good idea to provide a fall-back instruction in case the pattern (here: `;`) doesn't occur in the search string?

Comment: The default is \let\temp=\empty.

Comment: Many thanks, Fischer. But the text "\bfseries" disappear in output of \temp. How to keep it?

Comment: @ John Kormylo, what's the meaning of "The default is \let\temp=\empty."?

Comment: What do you mean by \bfseries disappears? It is a command and is executed when you call \temp, that's why the bbb is bold.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, what I want is to receive a substring before ";" of an original string. I mean, given the string "aaa  \bfseries bbb;some other text", I'll get the string text "aaa  \bfseries bbb". Here \bfseries is only a common string which I don't want it execute. This string "aaa  \bfseries bbb" will be used by other marco where \bfseries will execute.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer,an input argument which is devided into two parts by the character ";". I need to extract the forward part(before ;) as argument of tocolor tcbitemize, and the afterward part(behind ;) as argument of another tcolorbox. You see, one argument for two funtions. But if there are special characters(for example, fontupper=\bfseries), extraction of arguments derectly by xstring will fail.

Comment: @lyl - It would be helpful if you edited your posting to provide a more realistic explanation of what you're trying to achieve. For sure, it would facilitate coming up with answers that actually address your real objectives.

Comment: @lyl with Ulrike's answer, the `\bfseries` is not executed during `\StrBefore` but during the call of `\temp`. You can see that if you use the following: `\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\temp}`. It'll print `aaa \bfseries bbb`.

Comment: Many thanks all of you for all these helpful and valuable advices. I think Fischer and Skillmon's soluntion solve my problem. Yes, I need both expanded version and un-expanded version. I'm so sorry for not descriping my question clearly. Still, where can I find more details about marco \noexpandarg and \detokenize?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, \noexpandarg is a good way. If \StrBefore receive a marco(\cmd, for example) which stores "aaa  \bfseries bbb;some other text", how to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. (Lua has a very powerful string manipulation library.) The answer sets up a LaTeX macro called `\StringBefore`, which calls a Lua function that does the actual work. The macro `\StringBefore` is expandable; it can be made the argument of some other macro, as is done in the code below. Incidentally, I'm assuming that if the character(s) in the second argument aren't found in the search string, nothing should be returned.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luastringN" macro and "luacode" env.
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function string_before ( str, patt ) 
  n = string.find ( str, patt ) 
  if n then -- string.find made (at least) one match...
      tex.sprint ( string.sub ( str, 1, n-1) )
  else   -- no match -> print nothing
      tex.sprint ( "" ) 
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\StringBefore[2]{\directlua{ 
    string_before(\luastringN{#1},\luastringN{#2})}}
\begin{document}

\StringBefore{aaa {\bfseries bbb} ccc;some other text}{;}

\newcommand{\temp}{\StringBefore{ddd {\bfseries eee} \emph{ggg} hhh;dummy text}{;}}

\temp

\StringBefore{aaa {\bfseries bbb} ccc;some other text}{u} % no match

zzz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Mico. Because I know nothing about lua, this code is too complex for me to understand. Is there any other way to handle my question?

Comment: @lyl - Did you take a look at [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386177/5001)? You haven't provided any information as to what you're trying to achieve with the sub-string extraction business. Depending on your use case, it may be more straightforward to teach yourself the basics of Lua than it is to proceed with the tools of the `xstring` package. Lua has a very powerful string library (basically, a direct adaptation of the string library of C).

Comment: Maybe the OP can't use that LuaLaTeX code, but I can!